# Pass array to requirejs shim

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2

I am trying to get constant contacts script to work with magento 2 requirejs. (I tried adding it inline but it conflicts and causes errors)

Their script requires an array `localizedErrMap` and `jQuery` object.

I created `localizedErrMap.js`

```
define([],
    function(){
        var localizedErrMap = {};
        localizedErrMap['required'] =       'This field is required.';
        localizedErrMap['ca'] =             'An unexpected error occurred while attempting to send email.';
        localizedErrMap['email'] =          'Please enter your email address in name@email.com format.';
        localizedErrMap['birthday'] =       'Please enter birthday in MM/DD format.';
        localizedErrMap['anniversary'] =    'Please enter anniversary in MM/DD/YYYY format.';
        localizedErrMap['custom_date'] =    'Please enter this date in MM/DD/YYYY format.';
        localizedErrMap['list'] =           'Please select at least one email list.';
        localizedErrMap['generic'] =        'This field is invalid.';
        localizedErrMap['shared'] =         'Sorry, we could not complete your sign-up. Please contact us to resolve this.';
        localizedErrMap['state_mismatch'] = 'Mismatched State/Province and Country.';
        localizedErrMap['state_province'] = 'Select a state/province';
        localizedErrMap['selectcountry'] =  'Select a country';

        return localizedErrMap;
    }
);
```

and made this `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    "shim": {
        "constantcontact": {
            "deps":["jquery", "localizedErrMap"],
            "depnames":["jQuery", "localizedErrMap"]
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "localizedErrMap": "js/localizedErrMap",
        "constantcontact": "https://static.ctctcdn.com/h/contacts-embedded-signup-assets/1.0.2/js/signup-form"
    }

};
```

Then called it in the page with constant contact form like this:

```
<script>
   require(["constantcontact"]);
</script>
```

Their script throws the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: localizedErrMap is not defined

I cant modify their code as it's offsite, I need to make sure this array is passed through to the code.  What did I do wrong and how can I make sure the array is passed across?

Answer (score 1):

That `depnames` array you are using in `shim` is not something that RequireJS supports. The only reference I can find to it is in an issue report where someone [*suggested*](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/1160#issuecomment-47681204) supporting such an option but that was never implemented.

It looks like `constantcontact`, which is not an AMD module, expects to find a symbol `localizedErrMap` in the global space. In general, you have a few options:

1. You can add a build step to how you build your application to add a `define` call around the code in `constantcontact`, effectively turning it into an AMD-module. The [`wrapShim`](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/b8a6982d2923ae8389355edaa50d2b7f8065a01a/build/example.build.js#L68) option of `r.js` can be useful for this. However, you say that you cannot modify it so this option is off the table.
2. You can deliberately leak `localizedErrMap`. Such leaking is sometimes a viable solution for using libraries that are not AMD libraries. I prefer to avoid it but there are situations where it cannot be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding this to the CMS page inline.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var localizedErrMap = {};
            localizedErrMap['required'] =       'This field is required.';
            localizedErrMap['ca'] =             'An unexpected error occurred while attempting to send email.';
            localizedErrMap['email'] =          'Please enter your email address in name@email.com format.';
            localizedErrMap['birthday'] =       'Please enter birthday in MM/DD format.';
            localizedErrMap['anniversary'] =    'Please enter anniversary in MM/DD/YYYY format.';
            localizedErrMap['custom_date'] =    'Please enter this date in MM/DD/YYYY format.';
            localizedErrMap['list'] =           'Please select at least one email list.';
            localizedErrMap['generic'] =        'This field is invalid.';
            localizedErrMap['shared'] =         'Sorry, we could not complete your sign-up. Please contact us to resolve this.';
            localizedErrMap['state_mismatch'] = 'Mismatched State/Province and Country.';
            localizedErrMap['state_province'] = 'Select a state/province';
            localizedErrMap['selectcountry'] =  'Select a country';
            var postURL = 'https://visitor2.constantcontact.com/api/signup';
        </script>
        <script>
            require(["jquery"], function($){
                $.getScript('https://static.ctctcdn.com/h/contacts-embedded-signup-assets/1.0.2/js/signup-form.js');
            });
        </script>
```